# error con dateutil.relativedelta

Tags: python

Estoy dando mis primeros pasos con Python y visual studio code. Estoy probando a importar paquetes en un entorno virtual.

He importado dateutil, confirmando mediante comando pip freeze la versión que tengo instalada.

El caso que se me presenta es que cuando abro la carpeta donde está alojado el programa (src) en visual studio code no me presenta problemas. Sin embargo, si abro la carpeta raíz del programa (python) me salta error en la lectura del módulo datetutil. Además, me sale abajo un error que me está diciendo que el sistema no puede ejecutar scripts.

¿Podría alguien darme un poco de luz?

Gracias :)
[image: Imágenes adjuntadas]
[image: Imágenes adjuntadas]

Comment: Por favor [no publiques imagenes de código](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/21), publica el texto del código como tal. Lo mismo vale para los errores.

Comment: Hola FranDev, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, elimines a imagen y añadas tu código como texto, de esa forma tu pregunta será mejor recibida y evitarás recibir votos negativos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por vuestras recomendaciones. En cuanto me sea posible haré esas modificaciones. Sobre el problema en cuestión podéis comentarme algo? ^^